# Should I use capital letter in scientific tests for refering sections? I.e. Section 1.2 or section 1.2?

Tags: capitalization, science

The question is simple, should I write

"In this section..." or "In this Section"

"In this chapter..." or "In this Chapter"

?

Comment: Capitalization when referring to a specific section ("In Section 1.2, we demonstrate") should not imply capitalization when used as a noun ("In this section, we demonstrate"). These versions follow the style often used in technical editing. Check the style guide of the journal of interest for specific instructions.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There is no single right or wrong answer; such things are a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a suitable [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052) and be consistent in its application. Also see *[What are the capitalization rules for in-document references in scientific papers?](/questions/236091)*, *[Capitalization of “Theorem 1” in mathematics papers](/questions/28373/)*, and the related questions linked therefrom.